# Send Form Data to mySQL Database After JavaScript Validation via PHP(client side, server-side validation together)

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I am working on validating a signup page of a website using javascript and PHP methods.(client-side validation and server -side validation)

when I tried php connection on submit button, i was successfully getting the data in phpmyadmin database.
The problem is when I linked the html file of the signup page to a javascript validating user input,
the signup button in the page no longer works(its does nothing). So i am unable to enter the data through php and into the database.
When I removed "form id" in the form section of the html, the php connection works again.

I used javascript to validate fullname, username , email,  phone, password, and password2(for confirming again).

```
//validation rules javascript

fullname  = if client leaves the entry blank, or error
username  = if client leaves the entry blank, or error 
           / enter between 8 to 30 characters, or error
email     = if client leaves the entry blank, error 
           / correct email format, or error
phone     = if client leaves the entry blank, error 
           / correct phone no. format, or error
password  = if client leaves the entry blank, error 
           / enter between 8 to 20, english 
           / including at least one number and one special character
             , or error
password2 = if client leaves the entry blank, error 
          / checks if password = password2 matching, or error.
```

//signin.html//

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<!--
 // WEBSITE  : https://themefisher.com
 // TWITTER  : https://twitter.com/themefisher
 // FACEBOOK : https://www.facebook.com/themefisher
 // GITHUB   : https://github.com/themefisher/
-->

<html lang="en">
<head>

  <!-- Basic Page Needs
  ================================================== -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Craft Sutra</title>

  <!-- Mobile Specific Metas
  ================================================== -->
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="description" content="Construction Html5 Template">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=5.0">
  <meta name="author" content="Themefisher">
  <meta name="generator" content="Themefisher Constra HTML Template v1.0">
  
  <!-- Favicon -->
  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="images/favicon.png" />
  
  <!-- Themefisher Icon font -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="plugins/themefisher-font/style.css">
  <!-- bootstrap.min css -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="plugins/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  
  <!-- Animate css -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="plugins/animate/animate.css">
  <!-- Slick Carousel -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="plugins/slick/slick.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="plugins/slick/slick-theme.css">
  

</head>

<body id="body">
  <script>
    const hypenTel = (target) => {
      target.value = target.value
         .replace(/[^0-9]/g, '')
         .replace(/^(\d{2,3})(\d{3,4})(\d{4})$/, `$1-$2-$3`);
    }
  </script>
    
  <script defer src="signin_valid.js"></script>
   
<section class="signin-page">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
        <div class="block text-center">
          <div class="signinlogo">
            <a class="logo" href="index.html">
              <img src="images/logo.png" alt="">
            </a>
            <h2 style="font-family: 'Noto Sans KR', sans-serif; font-size: x-large" class="text-center">계정 만들기</h2>
            <form class="text-left clearfix" id="form" action="connectsignin.php" method="post">
              <div class="input-control">
                <input type="text" id="fullname" name="fullname" type="text" placeholder="이름">
                <div class="error"></div>
              </div>
              <div class="input-control">
                <input type="text" id="username" name="username" placeholder="아이디">
                <div class="error"></div>
              </div>
              <div class="input-control">
                <input type="text" id="email" name="email" placeholder="이메일(로그인시 사용)">
                <div class="error"></div>
              </div>
              <div class="input-control">
                <input type="text" oninput="hypenTel(this)" maxlength="13" id="phone" name="phone" placeholder="전화번호">
                <div class="error"></div>
              </div>
              <div class="input-control">
                <input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="비밀번호">
                <div class="error"></div>
              </div>
              <div class="input-control">
                <input type="password" id="password2" name="password2" placeholder="비밀번호 재입력">
                <div class="error"></div>
              </div>
              <div class="text-center">
                <button type="submit" style="font-size: small;" class="btn-main text-center">회원가입</button>
              </div>
          </div>
          </form>
          <p class="mt-20">이미 회원 등록하셨나요?<a href="login.html"> 로그인</a></p>
          <p><a href="forget-password.html"> 비밀번호를 잊으셨나요?</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</section>


  <!-- 
    Essential Scripts
    =====================================-->
    
    <!-- Main jQuery -->
    <script src="plugins/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap 3.1 -->
    <script src="plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap Touchpin -->
    <script src="plugins/bootstrap-touchspin/dist/jquery.bootstrap-touchspin.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Instagram Feed Js -->
    <script src="plugins/instafeed/instafeed.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Video Lightbox Plugin -->
    <script src="plugins/ekko-lightbox/dist/ekko-lightbox.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Count Down Js -->
    <script src="plugins/syo-timer/build/jquery.syotimer.min.js"></script>

    <!-- slick Carousel -->
    <script src="plugins/slick/slick.min.js"></script>
    <script src="plugins/slick/slick-animation.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Google Mapl -->
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCC72vZw-6tGqFyRhhg5CkF2fqfILn2Tsw"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="plugins/google-map/gmap.js"></script>

    <!-- Main Js File -->
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>
    
  
    <!-- Main Stylesheet -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style(signin+login).css">

 </body>
</html>
```

//javascript file//

```
const form      = document.getElementById('form');
const fullname  = document.getElementById('fullname');
const username  = document.getElementById('username');
const email     = document.getElementById('email');
const phone     = document.getElementById('phone');
const password  = document.getElementById('password');
const password2 = document.getElementById('password2');

form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    validateInputs();
});


const setError = (element, message) => {
    const inputControl = element.parentElement;
    const errorDisplay = inputControl.querySelector('.error');

    errorDisplay.innerText = message;
    inputControl.classList.add('error');
    inputControl.classList.remove('success')
}

const setSuccess = element => {
    const inputControl = element.parentElement;
    const errorDisplay = inputControl.querySelector('.error');

    errorDisplay.innerText = '';
    inputControl.classList.add('success');
    inputControl.classList.remove('error');
};

const isValidEmail = email => {
    const re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
    return re.test(String(email).toLowerCase());
}

const isValidPhone = phone => {
    const re = /^\d{2,3}-\d{3,4}-\d{4}$/;
    return re.test(String(phone).toLowerCase());
}

const isValidPassword = password => {
    const re = new RegExp("^(?=.{8,20}$)[a-zA-Z0-9._](?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#\$%\^&\*])");
    return re.test(password);
}

const isValidUsername = username => {
    const re = new RegExp("^(?=.{8,30}$)[a-zA-Z0-9._]");
    return re.test(username);
}

const validateInputs = () => {
    const fullnameValue  = fullname.value.trim();
    const usernameValue  = username.value.trim();
    const emailValue     = email.value.trim();
    const phoneValue     = phone.value.trim();
    const passwordValue  = password.value.trim();
    const password2Value = password2.value.trim();

    if(fullnameValue === '') {
        setError(fullname, '이름을 입력해 주세요.');
    } else {
        setSuccess(fullname);
    }

    if(usernameValue === '') {
        setError(username, '아이디를 입력해 주세요.');
    } else if (!isValidUsername(usernameValue)) {
        setError(username, '아이디는 8~30자로 입력해주세요.');
    } else {
        setSuccess(username);
    }

    if(emailValue === '') {
        setError(email, '이메일을 입력해 주세요.');
    } else if (!isValidEmail(emailValue)) {
        setError(email, '올바른 이메일을 입력해 주세요.');
    } else {
        setSuccess(email);
    }

    if(phoneValue === '') {
        setError(phone, '전화번호를 입력해 주세요.');
    } else if (!isValidPhone(phoneValue)) {
        setError(phone, '올바른 전화번호가 아닙니다');
    } else {
        setSuccess(phone);
    }

    if(passwordValue === '') {
        setError(password, '비밀번호을 입력해 주세요.');
    } else if (!isValidPassword(passwordValue)) {
        setError(password, '비밀번호는 영문 숫자 특수문자를 모두 포함하여 8~20자로 입력해 주세요.');
    } else {
        setSuccess(password);
    }

    if(password2Value === '') {
        setError(password2, '비밀번호를 확인해 주세요.');
    } else if (password2Value !== passwordValue) {
        setError(password2, "비밀번호가 일치하지 않습니다.");
    } else {
        setSuccess(password2);
    }
};
```

// PHP file //

```PHP
<?php
    $fullname  = $_POST['fullname'];   
    $username  = $_POST['username'];
    $email     = $_POST['email'];
    $phone     = $_POST['phone'];
    $password  = $_POST['password'];
    $password2 = $_POST['password2'];
    

    // Database connection
    $conn = new mysqli('localhost','root','','craft sutra');
    if($conn->connect_error){
        echo "$conn->connect_error";
        die("Connection Failed : ". $conn->connect_error);
    } else {
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("insert into signin(fullname, username, email, phone, password, password2) values(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
        $stmt->bind_param("sssiss", $fullname, $username, $email, $phone, $password, $password2);
        $execval = $stmt->execute();
        echo $execval;
        echo "회원가입이 완료됐습니다...";
        $stmt->close();
        $conn->close();
    }
?>
```

all the files(html, php, js) mentioned are located in this theme folder:
"C:\xampp\htdocs\craft sutra\theme"

Comment: so much useless code, while html5 directly integrates form validation, or with just a few lines of JavaScript...  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Form_validation

Comment: Could you point out where I need to make changes in the files?

Comment: you can directly use patern into input element; and you don't need to add 'error' div as HTML5 provide error messge for each input if nescesary...you don't need to use ID to form's elements,..

Comment: Please be more clear, I am understanding that you mean all validation code can be put in the html , and javascript is unneccesary? If yes, can you provide me another solution where I dont have to make changes to the files ?

Comment: yes, except if you want some personal customizations

Comment: Glad we are on the same page here. When I was making the files, I did try adding "required" in the input for some validations, but they looked ugly... That's why I am using javascript for better custimizations(like you said)